# How to keep the screen in landscape mode in Android

Tags: android

I have an activity which should always be displayed in **Landscape mode**. So i added `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`.

But the problem is when I rotate the device by *180 degrees*, the display is inverted. is there a way to handle this issue so that the screen elements are always shown correctly.?

Comment: So you want it to either be in landscape or reverse landscape?

Comment: @RobbyPond right now i am facing one issue in which i want my application to be landscape and reverse landscape as well. so what if i require in both the mode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So just for everyone information, this is what i did.

1. In Android manifest added android:screenOrientation="landscape".
2. In on resume method add these lines of code

> ```
> Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
> int orientation = display.getRotation();
>
> if(orientation==Surface.ROTATION_180)
> {
>       setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
> }
> ```

This way my screen is always positioned correctly even if user holds the device upside down.

Comment: it doesn't work for me, since it will not call onResume again after rotation

Answer (score 62):

Actually what you really want is to specify:

```
android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml.  This will listen to the sensor data while snapping between landscape and reverseLandscape.

Comment: +1 Thanx CaseyB, it just take 1 minute to implement both the orientation. Once again thanx for saving my valuable time.

Comment: FYI, it works only for Tablet, i have tested the same but it always display app in portrait mode by default i.e. its not working in phone

Comment: sensorLandscape was added into Froyo (2.2) so it will work on any devices that have that or later.

Comment: This rotates the view alright but doesn't fire any event. I need to capture the event when orientation change from normal to reverse view. How to do that?

Comment: Just wondering, why do you need that? Isn't landscape just landscape no matter what?

Answer (score 10):

Others have mentioned `sensorLandscape`...to do this programmatically in your activity (or a base activity), you can set your orientation to that:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
```

I'm doing it in `onResume()`. This will respect landscape and reverse landscape when you flip the device around 180 degrees in the middle of the activity, without having to use `onConfigurationChanged()`.

This was helpful to me since for tablets I need landscape/landscape reverse only, and for phones I need portrait/portrait reverse only, and don't want to do two separate AndroidManifest files. `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT` also exists.

Answer (score 2):

In the Android Manifest write this:

```
   android:configChanges="orientation"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

like in the example below.

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:configChanges="orientation"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

The good method is to use

```
setRequestedOrientation(6);
```

6 is the value for sensorLandscape but it seem's that there is no defined constant for it.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. This depends a bit on the framework version you're using as well. Try this ast a start:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

If that works great. If it dosen't you have to tell us a little more about the layout of your app.

Comment: Yes. i did that. here is what is put in my onResume method 

Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
  int orientation = display.getRotation();
  if((orientation==Surface.ROTATION_90) || (orientation==Surface.ROTATION_270)){
   setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
  }else if(orientation==Surface.ROTATION_180){
   setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);